# Tkinter - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set' - Dice Roll Simulator

Tags: python, tkinter, dice

The code i'm trying run is below. I'm trying to get the user input through a widget box and then run the while loop to simulate the Dice roll. I'm getting the below error.

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

def Dice_roll(event):

    while True:
        x.get()
        if x[0].lower() == 'y':
            m = random.randrange(1, 7)
            if m == 1:
                print("The number on the dice is", m)
            elif m == 2:
                print("The number on the dice is", m)
            elif m == 3:
                print("The number on the dice is", m)
            elif m == 4:
                print("The number on the dice is", m)
            elif m == 5:
                print("The number on the dice is", m)
            elif m == 6:
                print("The number on the dice is", m)
            else:pass

        if x[0].lower() == 'n':
           print("Thank you for playing the game :-)")
           break

x.delete(0, "end")
root = Tk()
x = Entry(root)
x.pack(side=LEFT)

Label(root, text="Want to roll the dice(Yes/No)?").pack(side=TOP)
Button.bind("<Button-1>",Dice_roll)
Button.pack(side=LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

Error Message is below: I am trying to get the input from Button1 which needs to passed to the Dice_roll function. This is my first time trying to use tkinter module. I am not sure if the functionality works for string values.

```
**AttributeError**              Traceback (most recent call last)  

<ipython-input-32-ce597da421bf> in <module>()
 45  
 46 Label(root, text="Want to roll the dice(Yes/No)?").pack(side=TOP)  
---> 47 Button.bind("<Button-1>",Dice_roll)  
 48 Button.pack(side=LEFT)  
 49  

~**\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py in bind**(self, sequence, func, add)  
   1243         of bound events are returned."""  
   1244  
-> 1245         return self._bind(('bind', self._w), sequence, func, add)  
   1246     def unbind(self, sequence, funcid=None):  
   1247         """Unbind for this widget for event SEQUENCE  the  

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_bind'
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your question.

Comment: My apologies this is my second time posting here. I have indented the code as well. I have added the error message i receive while implementing this code and what i am trying to achieve with the code. Please let me know if the objective is unclear. I would provide more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried to call `bind` on the `Button` class itself without actually creating a `Button` object (by contrast, with the `Label` you correctly created a `Label` object first, then called `pack` on it). You need to construct a `Button` first, *then* call `bind` on the new object. Your error occurred because you tried to call the method without binding it to an object, so the first positional argument (`"<Button-1>"`) got interpreted as `self`, and when it tried to invoke `Button` methods on it (in this case, `set`), everything broke.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That resolved the error once i created the button and then called bind on it.